# heroku can't load CSS/JS from bootstrap layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using two bootstrap layouts (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-creative and https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale) for my website
(https://fierce-ocean-39920.herokuapp.com/), and on Heroku, the pages with the creative layout appear with only html, while the pages with grayscale display perfectly fine.

My github: https://github.com/Conbonbot/Community_Service_Logger

I've tried using the maxcdn solution, I've put it in my application.html.erb, and it changes the layout a little bit, but doesn't actually load the creative layout, and it messes with the grayscale layout

I've installed both the rails_12factor and anjlab-bootstrap-rails gems, and again, nothing changes.

my new.html.erb (the part that's not working)

```
  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link href="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Plugin CSS -->
  <link href="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Theme CSS - Includes Bootstrap -->
  <link href="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="/assets/startbootstrap-creative/js/creative.min.js"></script>
```

I keep getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/startbootstrap-creative/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"):
```

for each line in the code shown above (only with different paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the heroku buildpack to heroku/ruby (bundler was giving me issues)

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

Then, I added nodejs to the buildpacks to use npm to install the layouts

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

Then I installed the layouts,

```
heroku run npm i startbootstrap-creative
heroku run npm i startbootstrap-grayscale
```